# Dropzone.js CSS

Tags: javascript, css, dropzone.js

I have a upload by `dropzone.js`. I added the next code to my JS:

```
 thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl) {
    var thumbnail = $('.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-image:last');
    thumbnail.css('background', 'url('+dataUrl+')');
    var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();
    var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');
    fotorama.push({img: dataUrl, thumb:dataUrl});   
 }
```

I have only one problem - when I upload more than one picture at the same time I get only the last picture.

[image]

This is the situation if I remove `:last`
[image: image2]

How can I solve this?

SOLVED!

Comment: You should prob select something inside `$fotoramaDiv` to apply the image to, using `.dz-image:last` will only ever set the last image (and removing `:last` will set every element to the same image). Could you show us the element stored in `$fotoramaDiv`?

Comment: The fotorama div is not importent,there is other plugin `fotorama.io` and this is working properly!

Comment: So, how do you know which element you should be adding the image to? Also, a small working example would be very helpful.

Comment: Always the last,And if I'm not wrong,the dropzone is going to upload one by one if `parralel upload:1`.

Comment: What you had works correctly for the last element, but clearly it's creating all of those elements before you're adding the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the next:

```
thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl) {
        var i=sessionStorage.getItem('uploaded_pic');
        if(typeof(dataUrl) != "undefined" && dataUrl !== null) {
            i++;
            sessionStorage.setItem('uploaded_pic', i);
            var selector='.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview:nth-child('+i+') .dz-image';
            alert(selector);
            var thumbnail = $(selector);
            thumbnail.css('background', 'url('+dataUrl+')');
            var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();
            var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');
            fotorama.push({img: dataUrl, thumb:dataUrl});
        }
```

And when the page is loaded I going to always reset the session storage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('uploaded_pic', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `thumbnail` selector `$('.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-image:last');` is reffered to only the `:last` element. You should remove the `:last` pseudoclass.

Answer (score 0):

form

```
<form action="/file-upload"
  class="dropzone"
  id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

JS

```
 thumbnail: function("#my-awesome-dropzone") {
var thumbnail = $('.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview');
thumbnail.css('background', 'url('+dataUrl+')');
var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();
var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');
fotorama.push({img: dataUrl, thumb:dataUrl});
```

}

JSFIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/gqbkhkxp/

Comment: Nothing. More worst than before.